# Segues not working (Table view/navigation controller/tab controller)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I am writing an iOS app that uses the service Parse. When I tap on a cell, it doesn't segue as I would expect. It appears that my "prepareForSegue" method is not being called. I used breakpoints to determine this, and the NSLog never outputs anything.  Here is my method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    NSLog(segue.identifier);
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showObjectDetails"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        //OfferDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [segue.destinationViewController setObject:object];
    }

}
```

The segue name is "showObjectDetails" if it matters, and it's coming from a list view. I used the Push selection segue. I have made sure that the Custom Class is set correctly in Interface Builder. I am using a Tab Bar controller, that references a NavigationController, that then displays the tableview.

Comment: How did you wire up your segue in the Storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the Segue Identifier has been set in the Storyboard, as below.

[image: Segue Identifier]

Comment: My interface looks slightly different (it doesn't have the Destination option), but I do have style set to Push, and the identifier is also set correctly.

Comment: Try: 
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showObjectDetails" sender:sender];`

Comment: In conjunction with this delegate method:
`(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`